# According to a temporary table (Table Schema and data)

Tags: temp-tables

According to a temporary table (Table Schema and data), how can i create a physical table and insert returned records to it?

Comment: I think you need to give us a bit more information about what you are trying to do.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hi,
```

in the below sample code , i am retriving columns from the temp table using the case condition..
in the step 2 we are checking for any column has been selected from the case statement..
in the step 3 we are selecting only the columns which have been retrieved from the above case stmnt..
in the step 4 we are creating the physical table with the columns names which have selected above and then inserting into it..
atlast drop both the tables

i hope this would help you

### step1:

```
  DECLARE @dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
  SELECT @dynsql =    
            CASE WHEN columnname1 >0 THEN ',columnname' ELSE '' END +                       
            CASE WHEN columnname2 >0 THEN ',columnname2' ELSE '' END +           
            .
            .
            CASE WHEN columnnamen >0 THEN ',columnnamen ' ELSE '' END                 
  FROM ##temptble     
  WHERE  condition  =  cond;
```

### step 2:

```
  IF(LEN(@dynsql) > 0)     
   BEGIN
```

### step 3:

```
   SET @dynsql = STUFF(@dynsql,1,1,'SELECT machinename, ') + ' FROM ##temptble'       
   EXEC(@dynsql)      
    END       
  decalre f nvarchar(max)
```

### step 4:

```
  set @f = STUFF(@dyncreate,1,6,'create table ven_temp( descriptionname nvarchar(111),' )  + '   int )'   
 exec(@f)   
  insert into ven_temp    
   EXEC(@dynsql)
```